# Maintain cookbook version for internal use

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

What is the best approach to maintain cookbook version for internal use - this is not public cookbooks.

- With every new provision increase cookbook version - in that case new stuff are applied to the node
- Work with single version of cookbook - on new provision delete the previous version and upload again. When there are same major features - then increase the version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow [semver](http://semver.org/) and treat all cookbooks same way (public, private). It's just a good habit. Internal cookbooks may require rollback (sometimes) and proper version management as well as public ones. I don't see any reason for having single version except extreme laziness.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer is correct, it is worth noting that the newer Policyfile+monorepo workflow(s) don't bother with version numbers because you're just working with snapshots, so in some cases you can sidestep this problem entirely.

Comment: That is one of my bits of training material for Policyfiles, yes.

Comment: I've never used such approach and I will take a look. Currently I'm a phase of refactoring our Chef project structure and I will check how I can integrate such approach. Our current cookbooks supports standard versioning.